# Microsoft Team Foundation Server - System.ArgumentException No node with tag "LastRefreshTime" exists under given node: Registration Entries

Tags: c#, tfs

I've been working on a solution that implements the namespaces for Team Foundation Server:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
```

I have a code block that works in debug mode from visual studio, however when deployed as a service it throws a `System.ArgumentException`, exception.

Here is the block that generates it:

```
    TfsConfiguration._tfsCollectionURL = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConstantValues.PubDeskTfsServerKeyName]);
    TfsConfiguration._tfsProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsConfiguration._tfsCollectionURL);
    TfsConfiguration._tfsWorkItemStore = (WorkItemStore)TfsConfiguration._tfsProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
```

The in the first line, the configuration manager pulls the URI of the TFS collection from a app.config file.

This is the error message is generated on the final line of code

What I've been getting....

> System.ArgumentException {"No node with tag \"LastRefreshTime\" exists under 
>   the given node: RegistrationEntries."}

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: What version of TFS Server and Client Object Model are you using? Not sure if that would be the cause though. Do you have the full stack trace, I might crack open ILSpy :)

Comment: Is there more error message?

Comment: Which API version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Team Explorer installed on the server if you are using old API version or you can try with the new TFS API: [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) without Team Explorer.